# Is it worth creating another method to simplify methods that repeat themselves?

Tags: java

I have several public methods in my code which are all the same :

```
public boolean modifyLastName(int nth, String lastName) {

    if (!isNthValid(nth)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (lastName.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
        if (book[i] != null) {
            count++;

            if (count == nth) {
                book[i].setLastName(lastName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Other than the obvious header where I have "modifyLastName", my 4 methods are identical except for `setLastName(lastName)` where it would be different `setTitle(title)`, `setDate(date)`.

I'm considering implementing a new method to pass the information into but I just can't see how this would help reducing the code, but also making sure that in the future I can update a single method if needed and everything would be taken care of.

Comment: We can't tell you if it will be "worth it".  It is a matter of opinion ... and highly context dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, which means that you don't need to repeat your book lookup code: (which would be a lot simpler if you didn't have nulls in your array. Should you be using a List instead?)

```
    public boolean modifyLastName(int nth, String lastName) {
        return updateBook(nth, b -> b.setLastName(lastName), lastName.length() != 0);
    }
    
    private boolean updateBook(int nth, Consumer<Book> operation, boolean valid) {
        if (!isNthValid(nth)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!valid) {
            return false;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
            if (book[i] != null) {
                count++;

                if (count == nth) {
                    operation.accept(book[i]);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know about the Consumer interface. I did some research and learned some new stuff.